# Event listener console logging that the click event target is on the root div in react component

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, dom-events, addeventlistener, css-transforms

I want to have a search bar with an auto suggestion feature. Right now there is a pop up div under the input with a list of buttons that I generate based on the search results from an API. Actually, I used CSS transform: scale(0) and transition to scale(1) to make the pop up div animate when popping up, I'm not sure if that's my problem.

I need to know which button the user is clicking on in the pop-up div.

I have attached an event listener to the document in the `componentDidMount` function. It works fine, and I can get a console.log of other elements being clicked, as normal... It doesn't seem to work for the buttons on the div which pop up after the input bar is active... it just keeps saying that `<div id="root">` has been clicked.

Please help .....

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.clickButton);
};

clickButton = (event) => {
        console.log('click triggered');
        console.log(event.target);}
};

showSearchResults = () => {
        ... conditional rendering
            return (
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button id="button">{this.state.value}</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            ....
};


Render() { 
.....
<div className="search__results">{this.showSearchResults()}</div>
....
};
```

CSS

```
.search-container {
        grid-area: search;
        align-items: start;
        position: relative;
    }

    .search {
        background: black;
        border: 1px solid ${blue};
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        font: inherit;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        color: ${blue};
    }

    .search:focus + div {
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: 350ms;
    }

    .search__results {
        position: absolute;
        height: 12rem;
        width: 17rem;
        background: white;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: 5;
        padding: 1px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: 350ms;
    }

    .search__results ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .search__results button {
        border: none;
        background: grey;
        width: 100%;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        font: inherit;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    .search__results button:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
```

Comment: Provide your code here

Comment: I've updated the original question, thanks

Comment: where is the click handler of button on div

Comment: I haven't got one yet will add one and see if it changes things

Comment: SOLVED it was hanging over into the next component, so I need to integrate the two components together so it doesn't extend to another component...

Comment: is there someway around this? am I going to have this problem with every header with a drop down menu I make?